# Difficulties while trying to create a post request to a mongoose data model that have multiple references

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am finding it difficult to create a post request for a data model with two references either because of the way my code is structured or my little experience in mongoose, will need some help, I am a little bit stuck here.

From the code, I know there should be some sort of Id passed between the front end and back end but some tricks I have tried have not really worked, I will need some fresh ideas on how to implement this on my current code thank you.

```
//NewInvoiceData - the data model I want to send the post requests
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const newInvoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {

        invoiceDate: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        invoiceDueDate: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        customerInfoInvoiceData: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'CustomerInfoInvoiceData'
        },
        itemsInvoiceData: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'ItemsInvoiceData'
        }

    },

    {
        timestamps: true
    }

)
module.exports = mongoose.model('NewInvoiceData', newInvoiceSchema)

//The two models the above model is referencing is as seen below
//customerInfoInvoiceData
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const NewInvoiceData = require('./NewInvoiceData');

const customerInfoInvoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        customerName: {
            type: String
        },
        customerPhoneNumber: {
            type: Number
        },
        customerAddress: {
            type: String,
            // required:true
        },
        customerState: {
            type: String
        },

        // newInvoiceData: {
        //     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //     ref: 'NewInvoiceData'
        // },

    },

    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)
module.exports = mongoose.model('CustomerInfoInvoiceData', customerInfoInvoiceSchema)

//ItemsInvoiceData
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const NewInvoiceData = require('./NewInvoiceData');


const itemsInvoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        productName: {
            type: String
        },
        costPrice: {
            type: Number
        },
        sellingPrice: {
            type: Number
        },
        unitOfMeasurement: {
            type: String
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number
        },

        // newInvoiceData: {
        //     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        //     ref: 'NewInvoiceData'
        // },
    },

    {
        timestamps: true
    }

)
module.exports = mongoose.model('ItemsInvoiceData', itemsInvoiceSchema)


//Controller Creating the post request
//newInvoiceController
const NewInvoiceData = require('../models/NewInvoiceData')
const CustomerInfoInvoiceData= require('../models/CustomerInfoInvoiceData')
const ItemsInvoiceData=require('../models/ItemsInvoiceData')
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')

const createNewInvoice = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { invoiceDate, invoiceDueDate, customerInfoInvoiceData, itemsInvoiceData } = req.body

    if (!invoiceDate || !invoiceDueDate || !customerInfoInvoiceData || !itemsInvoiceData) {

        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' })
    }
    const addNewInvoice = await NewInvoiceData.create({ invoiceDate, invoiceDueDate, customerInfoInvoiceData, itemsInvoiceData})

    if (addNewInvoice) {//created
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'New Item Recorded' })
        console.log(addNewInvoice)
      
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid Item' })
    }
})

//Here is my route
//newInvoiceRoute

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const newInvoiceController = require('../contollers/newInvoiceController')

router.route('/')
      .post(newInvoiceController.createNewInvoice) 
      .get(newInvoiceController.getNewInvoice)
      
module.exports = router


//React FrontEnd Code talking to the database via Axios (this is
just a snippet and not the complete react code)

const saveInvoiceDates = (e) => {
           e.preventDefault()
         Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/newInvoice', {invoiceDate, invoiceDueDate})
            .then((response) => { alert('TRANSACTION CREATED') }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    const saveCustomerInvoiceInfo = (e)=>{
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/customerInvoiceInfo', 
        {customerName, customerAddress, customerPhoneNumber, customerState})
            .then((response) => { alert('TRANSACTION CREATED') }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    const saveItemsInvoiceDetails = (e)=>{
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/itemInvoiceInfo', 
        {productName, costPrice, sellingPrice, unitOfMeasurement, quantity})
            .then((response) => { alert('TRANSACTION CREATED') }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```